# Filter to move message sent to a specific alias email address

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook-2010

How do I set up a filter to move incoming messages based on the email address it was sent to.  I have a few different email accounts setup in my Outlook, for example:

- linger@zzz.com with an alias of ~ info@zzz.com
- whatever@zzz.com

I want any messages received for **info@zzz.com** to be moved to the **zzzInfo** folder under my Inbox.

Looking at the Rules Wizard it looks like I would have to select **Apply rule on messages I receive**:

[image]

But I don't know what to select next out of the following list:

[image]

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: The incoming mail rules in Outlook should support this easily. Did they not work as expected for you? What were the results?

Comment: Well since you're a person, try the one that says "Sent To People or Public Group". ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I didn't understand your question completely wrong, all you need to do is the below,

1. [Create a new Rule](http://office.microsoft.com/en-in/outlook-help/manage-email-messages-by-using-rules-HA010355682.aspx#_Toc363829253) (Ref. section "Create a rule based on senders or recipients of a message")
2. Set the filtering condition to be "Sent to specific email addresses"
3. Configure the email address and the folder it needs to be moved to

Note: I currently don't have access to Outlook to provide you with screenshots or the exact steps. But the [link](http://office.microsoft.com/en-in/outlook-help/manage-email-messages-by-using-rules-HA010355682.aspx#_Toc363829253) provided should help.

Comment: @linger He's telling you the section of the document he linked to look at.